# Is there a way to intensify the colours of an image?

Tags: light

I've added an image. Unfortunately, when I render the scene the image looks washed out.

Is there a way to intensify the colours of an image?

Many thanks,
Meri

Comment: Please specify Cycles or Blender Internal render engines. Adding that as a tag really helps us post relevant answers. I have posted a Cycles answer just in case that is what you want

Answer (score 3):

Use the Hue/Saturation node. Increasing the Saturation will increase the color intensity.

[image]

Note that there are other factors that could be resulting in a washed out render. Also this is a Cycles specific answer.

Comment: You can use the color correction node too. It will give you more options an  a more precise way to affect the image.